# Using OCI8 Module to See OracleDB

Tags: 7, database

I have an external oracle db I'd like to use to show data in views. Has anyone used the [OCI8](https://www.drupal.org/project/oci8) module, if so, (sorry for my ignorance) how do we see the data? Do I need to create a custom module and hook into it? I cannot find any how to on this.

The readme says: 1) Build out OCI8OracleSelectQuery class which will mimic Drupal's SelectQuery. This would include writing an oci8_db_select() function to create these

Where do I do this? Thanks!

Comment: Are you familiar with the [Forena](https://www.drupal.org/project/forena) module, which also supports Oracle DBs?

Comment: I looked into that also...

Answer (score 2):

That module provides a very basic API only; no UI, no methods to display/format data, and no integration with the Views module.

It currently provides developers with:

- A database connection class for Oracle
- A simple Oracle-specific version of `db_query`
- A simple Oracle-specific version of `db_query_range`

and literally nothing else.

So yes, in order to see any data using this module, you're going to need to create your own module which uses the couple of query functions it provides, and displays the results in whatever way makes sense.

For something more automated, you could try the technique mentioned [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/33643/views-and-external-db-oracle) to hook into Views and force it to use a different database for certain tables (which can theoretically be in an Oracle DB). I've never tried that so I can't comment on its effectiveness, or if it's genuinely even an option. Something tells me that you'd need a PDO connection to Oracle for that to work, but I might be wrong.

As an aside, the line you quoted from the readme looks like a TODO note; the maintainer is probably saying that the functionality hasn't been implemented yet, but that developers who want to make proper use of the module will probably find it beneficial to implement that per their requirements.